# They were watching, SD makes a difference

Tags: discussion

This is not a very serious post, just to congratulate you all that Sound Design for something that happened today.

I posted [this](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/20480/behringer-x32-digital-feedback-loop) question, after "googling" for months and many emails with Behringer's support without getting proper answers on my problem. But suddenly, because I posted it here on SD, they listen, and one of their Senior Specialist joins SD today and provide a proper answer!

SD makes a difference!

Comment: What a fantastic story Sergio, thanks for taking a moment to share it with us.

Comment: @TimPost, SD was the one to help me :)

Comment: That makes me so happy to hear!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is awesome, and precisely how companies can take advantage of our platform to share knowledge about their products. It's a win for everyone, because the knowledge that they share has a *much* broader exposure; had this been over the phone it probably wouldn't have helped anyone but you, unless of course you happened upon a question asking the same thing and decided to share.

Speaking of that, I'd like to remind everyone that [it's perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) using the site. If you run into a particularly odd problem with equipment and get a working answer from the company, or just figure it out on your own, feel *absolutely* free to ask a question describing the problem that you had and then post what worked in an answer.

Yay for Behringer for the win on this, I hope they continue to monitor the [behringer](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behringer) tag and chime in again!

Comment: Good point about the Behringer tag! Posted that as a comment under the answer there